# How can shared memory be locked in php (shmop)

Tags: php

Please how can shared memory created in PHP using shmop (not shm if that matters) be locked and unlocked? Does this require libraries?

It seems shmop_read() runs while shmop_write() is still writing because value read has part of old and new values.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot explicity lock a shared memory segment, but you can open it in an exclusive mode, e.g.

```
shmop_open($shm_key, "n", 0644, 100);
```

Quoting http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shmop-open.php

> "n" create a new memory segment (sets IPC_CREATE|IPC_EXCL) use this flag when you want to create a new shared memory segment but if one already exists with the same flag, fail. This is useful for security purposes, using this you can prevent race condition exploits.

Comment: The shared memory is already created. The codes are to modify it content. Using shmop_open($shm_key, "n", 0644, 100); will always fail since the shared memory is already created. Two sections of code are writing to the shared memory. How can one of them be blocked if the other is writing?

Comment: @Osofem just `shmop_close` the segment after writing to it. That won't destroy it.

Comment: That does not solve the problem. the link by @ljubiccica just enlighten me, the shmop_read is picking up part of old and new values, which means read was called while write was still going on.

Comment: @Osofem that's why you should open it with 'n'. While you write it to then, no other process can open it. Then you close it. Open it elsewhere and read from it.

Comment: Creating or opening the shared memory while it already exist with 'n' will fail so not applicable. This is the situation, there are three sections. Section One open/create the shared memory segment and write/update it content. Section Two update what is already written into the segment while the Section Three read what is in the segment. Any of these sections can run at any time. Opening it with 'n' in section 1 & 2 will not work because the segment ALREADY EXIST!

Comment: @Osofem yes, exactly. You will not be able to create or open the segment when it's already open elsewhere. That's the best you can get for locking.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest use `sem_acquire`, `sem_release` to do atomical operations.

Answer (score 0):

I found some information about shared memory locking in PHP.

On this page user claims to have used "(...) the system memory functions of mmcache very successfully. They abstract all the tough stuff." ([link](http://www.devnetwork.net/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=28924))

And on Turck MMCache's page this:
 - new API functions mmcache_lock and mmcache_unlock were implemented

[turck-mmcache](http://turck-mmcache.sourceforge.net/index_old.html)

Php5 should be supported. Hope maybe you can start from here...

Comment: This is effectively a link only answer. [We do not like these](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Please include the relevant portions of the link

Comment: Exactly the same problem am having here... The shmop_read is picking up part of old and new values.

Comment: Yes, Gordon and Osofem, I agree with you both. I am pretty new here and I wanted to help. Only yesterday I learned I can comment on questions and that is where this thing probably belongs. I can delete my answer if you think the info is misleading.
KR

Comment: @ljubiccica you could delete the answer or - better - quote the relevant content from the linked sites.